# How to open txvpck files? (JBuilder UML diagrams)

Tags: uml, diagram, jbuilder

I have UML diagrams created long ago with **JBuilder**, a Java IDE apparently defunct since 2008. I am unable to download previous installers, as the product is not even mentioned anymore on the editor website.

The files are XML-based with the extension **txvpck**, here's an example of their contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodeSet version="1.0">
    <view uin="id5n25le5bftm2ge5bfvjng">
        <property name="$metaclass" value="Package Diagram"/>
        <property name="@__options" value=""/>
        <reference df-class-name="reference" referencedUin="design:view:::idv3x1e5bftm2ge5bfvkxc">
            <property name="$shortcutReference" value="true"/>
            <property name="@__fqn" value="uml:package:MyProduct:src:com"/>
            <property name="bounds" value="10,10,102,184"/>
        </reference>
        <property name="$defaultDiagram" value=""/>
    </view>
</nodeSet>
```

Is there a way to open these files with another UML tool or library, and convert them to an usable format?

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I also worked with Borland/Embacadero tools,... . Usually it is possible to open the UML files from one of those tools with an other one, and I expect that they still support those legacy files. So youcan open it with any newer version of a Borland/Emba tools that has integrated UML support. Maybe an professional edition, e.g, Delphi, would be sufficient to view your old model.